# Using Dictionary<T, Func<List, bool>> to Find Most Common Occurrences In List in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda, delegates, func

Assuming I have my C# code defined like below, I would like to return to my console an output that shows type of fuel most commonly found in the List or cars.

```
// set delegates defining rules as a function that takes list of cars and returns an int
Func<List<Car>, int> CountElectric = (cars) => cars
    .GroupBy(c => c.IsElectric == true).Count(); // count electric cars

Func<List<Car>, int> CountGassoline = (cars) => cars
    .GroupBy(c => c.FuelType == FuelTypes.Gassoline).Count(); // count cars using gassoline

Func<List<Car>, int> CountDiesel = (cars) => cars
    .GroupBy(c => c.FuelType == FuelTypes.Diesel).Count(); // Count cars using diesel

// Add rules to dictionary of (Key=CarType, Value=Func<List<Car>, bool>
CarsRules = new Dictionary<CarType, Func<List<Car>, int>>()
{
    {FueldType.Electric, CountElectric},
    {FueldType.Diesel,CountDiesel},
    {FueldType.Gassoline, CountGassoline}
};

// Create List of Cars and add some cars
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();

cars.Add(new Car() 
{Id = Guid, Name = "Tesla", IsElectric = true, FuelType = FuelTypes.Electric};

cars.Add(new Car() 
{Id = Guid, Name = "VW", IsElectric = false, FuelType = FuelTypes.Gassoline};

cars.Add(new Car() 
{Id = Guid, Name = "Toyota", IsElectric = false, FuelType = FuelTypes.Gassoline};

cars.Add(new Car() 
{Id = Guid, Name = "Volvo", IsElectric = false, FuelType = FuelTypes.Diesel};
```

In above list of cars, Gassoline is most common.  How do I find that out?
I.E I want to display on Console just "Gassoline"

If I had a tie in the list above, for example 2 cars using Gasoline and 2 cars using Diesel, how would I found and return both?
I.E I want to display on Console both "Gassoline" and "Diesel"

I am having difficult understanding this kind of structure and I am thinking to do it oldfashioned way like below but it is clear to me that there should be more elegant way to do it with Func delegates

```
public List<string> GetMostUsedFuelTypes(List<Car> cars)
{
    List<string> winners = new List<string>();

    int CountElectric = 0;
    int CountGassoline = 0;
    int CountDiesel = 0;

    foreach(var car in cars)
    {
        // Count and return fuel type that occurs most, if a tye, return the highest counts
    }

    return winners;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion for improvement unrelated to the question: `Func<List<Car>, bool> CountElectric = (cars) => cars.GroupBy(c => c.IsElectric == true).Count();` may be better as `Func<List<Car>, bool> CountElectric = (cars) => cars.Count(c => c.IsElectric == true);` And if the type of `IsElectric` is `bool` (rather than `bool?`) then you can also remove the `==true`.

Comment: `Func<List<Car>, int> CountElectric = (cars) => cars.GroupBy(c => c.IsElectric == true).Count()` doesn't count how many electric cars. It counts how many outcomes there are for `c.IsElectric == true` - which is a maximum of two. What you want is `Func<List<Car>, int> CountElectric = (cars) => cars.Where(c => c.IsElectric == true).Count()`.

Comment: @Enigmativity ...which can then be improved further, since doing a "Where" followed by a "Count" is wasteful: it creates a list of objects and then counts them. You can change the "Where" into a "Count" with a lambda expression which just keeps a count as it goes. That leaves you with the value in my preceding comment, although your explanation was much clearer than mine. :)

Comment: @Richardissimo - There's virtually no difference in the run-time performance of doing a `Where`/`Count` versus a `Count` with a lambda.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yeah, you're right, because I was wrong to say it creates a list, it's just processing an enumerable. `(cars) => cars.Count(car => car.IsElectric)` is still easier to read though.

Comment: @Richardissimo - I prefer the other approach as it is easier to refactor and, in my opinion, it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure `Dictionary<CarType, Func<List<Car>, int>>` is the wrong type to do this kind of thing. You can combine two `int` values to get an accurate count if you try to combine types with overlapping subsets.

Here's what I would do:

```
var CarsRules = new Dictionary<FuelTypes, Func<List<Car>, IEnumerable<Car>>>()
{
    { FuelTypes.Electric, cs => cs.Where(c => c.IsElectric) },
    { FuelTypes.Diesel, cs => cs.Where(c => c.FuelType == FuelTypes.Diesel) },
    { FuelTypes.Gassoline, cs => cs.Where(c => c.FuelType == FuelTypes.Gassoline) },
}

List<Car> cars = new List<Car>()
{
    new Car(Guid.NewGuid(), "Tesla", true, FuelTypes.Electric),
    new Car(Guid.NewGuid(), "VW", false, FuelTypes.Gassoline),
    new Car(Guid.NewGuid(), "Toyota", false, FuelTypes.Gassoline),
    new Car(Guid.NewGuid(), "Volvo", false, FuelTypes.Diesel),
};

Console.WriteLine($"Electric: {CarsRules[FuelTypes.Electric](cars).Count()}");
Console.WriteLine($"Gassoline: {CarsRules[FuelTypes.Gassoline](cars).Count()}");
Console.WriteLine($"Diesel: {CarsRules[FuelTypes.Diesel](cars).Count()}");
Console.WriteLine($"Gassoline & Diesel: {CarsRules[FuelTypes.Gassoline](cars).Union(CarsRules[FuelTypes.Diesel](cars)).Count()}");
```

This requires these types defined:

```
public enum FuelTypes
{
    Electric, Gassoline, Diesel
}

public sealed class Car : IEquatable<Car>
{
    private readonly Guid _Id;
    private readonly string _Name;
    private readonly bool _IsElectric;
    private readonly FuelTypes _FuelType;

    public Guid Id { get { return _Id; } }
    public string Name { get { return _Name; } }
    public bool IsElectric { get { return _IsElectric; } }
    public FuelTypes FuelType { get { return _FuelType; } }

    public Car(Guid Id, string Name, bool IsElectric, FuelTypes FuelType)
    {
        _Id = Id;
        _Name = Name;
        _IsElectric = IsElectric;
        _FuelType = FuelType;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Car)
            return Equals((Car)obj);
        return false;
    }

    public bool Equals(Car obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<Guid>.Default.Equals(_Id, obj._Id)) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(_Name, obj._Name)) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<bool>.Default.Equals(_IsElectric, obj._IsElectric)) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<FuelTypes>.Default.Equals(_FuelType, obj._FuelType)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 0;
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<Guid>.Default.GetHashCode(_Id);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(_Name);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<bool>.Default.GetHashCode(_IsElectric);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<FuelTypes>.Default.GetHashCode(_FuelType);
        return hash;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{{ Id = {0}, Name = {1}, IsElectric = {2}, FuelType = {3} }}", _Id, _Name, _IsElectric, _FuelType);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Car left, Car right)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(left, null))
        {
            return object.ReferenceEquals(right, null);
        }

        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Car left, Car right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I just thought of an approach more like your current one. I'll post it later when I have time to do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
var mostCommonFuelType =
    cars
        .GroupBy(car => car.FuelType)
        .OrderBy(carsByFuelType => carsByFuelType.Count())
        .Select(carsByFuelType => carsByFuelType.Key
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you need a custom rule, just make the rule select a key to use in its groupings. Unless they’re not mutually exclusive, in which case you’d also need to use a SelectMany and return pairs of key and value.

Comment: No, that is not what I am asking.  I am talking about the CarRules dictionary above which has CarType as Key and a Func delegate as value.  The Func is used to test and return boolean

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dictionary of how many cars are in each fuel type, and then list which fuel types have the largest count as follows...

```
var fuelTypeCountDictionary = cars
    .GroupBy(car => car.FuelType)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
var max = fuelTypeCountDictionary.Values.Max();
var maxFuelTypes = fuelTypeCountDictionary.Where(x => x.Value == max).Select(x => x.Key);
string mostUsedFuelTypes = string.Join(", ", maxFuelTypes);
Console.WriteLine(mostUsedFuelTypes);
```

For the example data given, this would display on Console just "Gassoline".

If there was a tie, for example 2 cars using Gasoline and 2 cars using Diesel, it would display on Console "Gassoline, Diesel".

P.S. "Gassoline" should only have one "s".

Comment: No, that is not what I am asking. I am talking about the CarRules dictionary above which has CarType as Key and a Func delegate as value. The Func is used to test and return boolean

Comment: @pixel The `Func`s in the posted code don't return a Boolean. They return an `int`. The title of this question is similarly faulty. But if the title and your comment is correct, and it's just the posted code which is faulty, I can provide a solution based on a dictionary of Predicates...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out how to invoke the Func delegate in my dictionary CarRules and pass it List of Car objects.  If someone else needs smtg like this, this is how I did it for example to find if a car is electric.

```
int countElectric = CarsRules[FueldType.Electric].Invoke(cars);
```

For example, above will invoke Func delegate CountElectric which takes List of cars and returns an int.

Using this, it should be easy to figure out what type of cars are mostly present in the list

Comment: No, that is not what I you're asking. Every one of the people trying to help answer you had the exact same understanding of your question: 
"In above list of cars, Gassoline is most common. How do I find that out?" This answers a different question: "How do I invoke a function stored in a dictionary?" That has *very little* to do with the code you posted.

Comment: Not an answer to the question asked

Answer (score 0):

Since you specifically want to use the "CarsRules" dictionary as the driver for this, you can adapt my other answer to fit; but first you need to fix the bug in the `Count*` `Func`s. At the moment they return an answer of 0, 1 or 2, no matter how many cars you put in the list; and it's not returning what you think. *For example if you put a single Gasoline car in the list, then CountElectric will return 1*. To fix that...

```
Func<List<Car>, bool> CountElectric = (cars) => cars.GroupBy(c => c.IsElectric == true).Count();
```

needs to be

```
Func<List<Car>, bool> CountElectric = (cars) => cars.Count(c => c.IsElectric == true);
```

And if the type of IsElectric is `bool` (rather than `bool?`) then you can also remove the `==true` to make it even simpler.

That change needs to be made to all 3 of those `Func`s.

So now that the `Func's in the dictionary do what is required to answer the question, you can just adapt my previous answer as follows:

```
var fuelTypeCountDictionary = CarsRules
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.Invoke(cars));
var max = fuelTypeCountDictionary.Values.Max();
var maxFuelTypes = fuelTypeCountDictionary.Where(x => x.Value == max).Select(x => x.Key);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", maxFuelTypes));
```